# django 2 deploy to heroku fail - at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed"

Tags: django, heroku, deployment

My build succeeded but my heroku website returns me with error.
I use heroku logs --tail to see the error messages.
Here is what it says:

> 2019-01-23T17:33:34.339263+00:00 app[web.1]: File
> "/app/notetaking/prod_settings.py", line 4
> 2019-01-23T17:33:34.339264+00:00 app[web.1]: SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER =
> ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO','https') 2019-01-23T17:33:34.339266+00:00
> app[web.1]: ^ 2019-01-23T17:33:34.339267+00:00 app[web.1]:
> SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
>
> Build succeeded
> 2019-01-23T17:34:37.203663+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/"
>
> host=multilingualnotetaking.herokuapp.com request_id=f964ab62-fac9-40f8-84a5-26bea61f183d fwd="39.10.71.43" dyno=web.1 connect=5001ms service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
>
> 2019-01-23T17:34:38.222491+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=multilingualnotetaking.herokuapp.com request_id=069cc8d6-41d9-4d13-b8e2-be0a982b1279 fwd="39.10.71.43" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

proc_settings.py(**I strongly doubt that this file is not valid.**)

```
import notetaking.settings
import os
STATIC_ROOT='staticfiles'
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO','https')
 ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
 DEBUG = False
import dj_database_url
DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config()
}
```

Procfile:

```
web: gunicorn --pythonpath notetaking notetaking.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT 
gunicorn project.wsgi:application --preload --workers 1
```

runtime.txt

```
python-3.7.1
```

requirements.txt

```
dj-database-url==0.5.0
dj-static==0.0.6
Django==2.1.5
djangorestfra

mework==3.9.1
gunicorn==19.9.0
mysqlclient==1.4.1
numpy==1.16.0
pandas==0.23.4
Pillow==5.4.1
psycopg2==2.7.7
python-dateutil==2.7.5
pytz==2018.9
six==1.12.0
static3==0.7.0
xlrd==1.2.0
```

**heroku restart** doesn't work for me.
I am using font-awesome, and I don't know if this will cause problem when deploying.

Answer (score 0):

changing the Procfile worked for me
form

```
web: gunicorn django_project.wsgi
```

to

```
web: gunicorn django_project.wsgi:application --log-file - --log-level debug
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
manage.py migrate
```